# Configure NCS540 IOS XR router works as Layer 2 switch

Tags: cisco-ios, cisco-ios-xr

I have an NCS 540 Router and would like to config it as an L2 Switch. In the diagram, PC2 and PC3 should get the IP addresses from pfSense(DHCP and DNS). How can I setup the trunk port for the NCS540 router? Thank you
[image]

Comment: Technically, I would like to use the router as a managed switch for testing.

Comment: You can configure IRB. Create a BVI interface, then add interfaces to the bridge group.

Answer (score 2):

I think that router is gigantic overkill for testing managed switch configuration, especially as it is definitely not designed to be a switch. You can configure a BVI on it and add interfaces to the bridge and I suppose that is similar to a switch but it is not similar to many other managed switches so you would be learning how to do things in a way that doesn't really apply to a lot of other switches that are primarily designed as switches.

Here is the guide on BVI configuration and related.

https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/iosxr/ncs5xx/interfaces/78x/b-interfaces-hardware-component-cg-78x-ncs540/int-routing-bridging.html

Comment: Thank you for your response. I totally agree that the router is way overkill for this lab. We want to utilize the PTP feature to set up FlexRan backhaul. We will deploy it as a carrier Ethernet router later on.